# Изменить библиотеку с android.app на android.support.v4.app

Tags: android, java

Есть класс с библиотекой `android.app.Fragment`, надо перейти на `android.support.v4.app.Fragment;`.

```
import by.sviter.allbest.adapter.NavDrawerListAdapter;
import by.sviter.allbest.model.NavDrawerItem;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.content.res.Configuration;
import android.content.res.TypedArray;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle;
import android.support.v4.widget.DrawerLayout;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.app.*;

public class MainActivity extends Activity {
    private DrawerLayout mDrawerLayout;
    private ListView mDrawerList;
    private ActionBarDrawerToggle mDrawerToggle;

    // nav drawer title
    private CharSequence mDrawerTitle;

    // used to store app title
    private CharSequence mTitle;

    // slide menu items
    private String[] navMenuTitles;
    private TypedArray navMenuIcons;

    private ArrayList<NavDrawerItem> navDrawerItems;
    private NavDrawerListAdapter adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mTitle = mDrawerTitle = getTitle();

        // load slide menu items
        navMenuTitles = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.nav_drawer_items);

        // nav drawer icons from resources
        navMenuIcons = getResources()
                .obtainTypedArray(R.array.nav_drawer_icons);

        mDrawerLayout = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
        mDrawerList = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_slidermenu);

        navDrawerItems = new ArrayList<NavDrawerItem>();

        // adding nav drawer items to array
        // Home
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[0], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(0, -1)));
        // Find People
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[1], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(1, -1), true, " 10 "));
        // Photos
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[2], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(2, -1), true, " 15 "));
        // Pages
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[3], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(3, -1), true, "10"));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[4], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(4, -1), true, "12"));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[5], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(5, -1), true, "15"));
        // What's hot, We  will add a counter here
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[6], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(6, -1), true, "закрыт"));
        navDrawerItems.add(new NavDrawerItem(navMenuTitles[7], navMenuIcons.getResourceId(7, -1), true, "закрыт"));

        // Recycle the typed array
        navMenuIcons.recycle();

        mDrawerList.setOnItemClickListener(new SlideMenuClickListener());

        // setting the nav drawer list adapter
        adapter = new NavDrawerListAdapter(getApplicationContext(),
                navDrawerItems);
        mDrawerList.setAdapter(adapter);

        // enabling action bar app icon and behaving it as toggle button
        getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        getActionBar().setHomeButtonEnabled(true);

        mDrawerToggle = new ActionBarDrawerToggle(this, mDrawerLayout,
                R.drawable.ic_drawer, //nav menu toggle icon
                R.string.app_name, // nav drawer open - description for accessibility
                R.string.app_name // nav drawer close - description for accessibility
        ) {
            public void onDrawerClosed(View view) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to show action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }

            public void onDrawerOpened(View drawerView) {
                getActionBar().setTitle(mDrawerTitle);
                // calling onPrepareOptionsMenu() to hide action bar icons
                invalidateOptionsMenu();
            }
        };
        mDrawerLayout.setDrawerListener(mDrawerToggle);

        if (savedInstanceState == null) {
            // on first time display view for first nav item
            displayView(0);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Slide menu item click listener
     * */
    private class SlideMenuClickListener implements
            ListView.OnItemClickListener {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
                long id) {
            // display view for selected nav drawer item
            displayView(position);
        }
    }

//  @Override
//  public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
//      getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
//      return true;
//  }

/*  @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // toggle nav drawer on selecting action bar app icon/title
        if (mDrawerToggle.onOptionsItemSelected(item)) {
            return true;
        }
        // Handle action bar actions click
        switch (item.getItemId()) {
    //  case R.id.action_settings:
    //  return true;
        default:
            return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
        }
    }

    /* *
     * Called when invalidateOptionsMenu() is triggered
     */
    @Override
    public boolean onPrepareOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // if nav drawer is opened, hide the action items
        // boolean drawerOpen = mDrawerLayout.isDrawerOpen(mDrawerList);
        // menu.findItem(R.id.action_settings).setVisible(!drawerOpen);
        return super.onPrepareOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    /**
     * Diplaying fragment view for selected nav drawer list item
     * */
    private void displayView(int position) {
        // update the main content by replacing fragments
        Fragment fragment = null;

        switch (position) {
        case 0:
            fragment = new a1();
            break;
        case 1:
            fragment = new a2();
            break;
        case 2:
            fragment = new a3();
            break;
        case 3:
            fragment = new a4();
            break;
        case 4:
            fragment = new a5();
            break;
        case 5:
            fragment = new a6();
            break;
        case 6:
            fragment = new a7();
            break;
        case 7:
            fragment = new a8();
            break;
        default:
            break;
        }

        if (fragment != null) {
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();
            fragmentManager.beginTransaction()
                .replace(R.id.frame_container, fragment).commit();
            // update selected item and title, then close the drawer
            mDrawerList.setItemChecked(position, true);
            mDrawerList.setSelection(position);
            setTitle(navMenuTitles[position]);
            mDrawerLayout.closeDrawer(mDrawerList);
        } else {
            // error in creating fragment
            Log.e("MainActivity", "Error in creating fragment");
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void setTitle(CharSequence title) {
        mTitle = title;
        getActionBar().setTitle(mTitle);
    }

    /**
     * When using the ActionBarDrawerToggle, you must call it during
     * onPostCreate() and onConfigurationChanged()...
     */

    @Override
    protected void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);
        // Sync the toggle state after onRestoreInstanceState has occurred.
        mDrawerToggle.syncState();
    }

    @Override
    public void onConfigurationChanged(Configuration newConfig) {
        super.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
        // Pass any configuration change to the drawer toggls
        mDrawerToggle.onConfigurationChanged(newConfig);
    }

}
```

Надо, чтобы все фрагменты а1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7, a8 были на библиотеке `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`, логично, что и класс `MainActivity` тоже должен быть на этой же библиотеке. Но когда я ее ставлю, то выбивает ошибку в коде на: `FragmentManager fragmentManager = getFragmentManager();`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1) В support library надо класс активити расширять от ActionBarActivity, а не Activity.

2) Вместо

```
getFragmentManager();
```

надо пользовать метод

```
getSupportFragmentManager();
```

Comment: Теперь пишет ошибку

>aapt:error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name 'AppBase Theme'.

В манифесте стоит: android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar" и в values/styles стоит <style name="AppTheme" parent="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Light.DarkActionBar">

Что его не устраивает?

Comment: @sviter-pro, у вас, возможно, в проекте есть папки типа "values-v11", "values-v14". Посмотрите их на предмет файла "styles" c объявлением тем.
Также посмотрите в манифесте все объявления активити с атрибутом "android:style".

Comment: Извиняюсь за тупость! Их убрать или добавить, если нет?

Comment: @sviter-pro, если их нет, то добавлять не надо.

Ваша проблема в том, что компилятор где-то в проекте находит тему, 'AppBase Theme'. Просто просмотрите проект на её наличие и удалите\ измените все её упоминания. 

Если нет вышеупомянутых папок, то проверьте ещё раз манифест и файл "styles" в папке "values";

Comment: При запуске вылетает ошибка: https://yadi.sk/i/yu-f0R9Qck4Zk

Comment: @sviter-pro, 
Ну, если у вас активити расширена от ActionBarActivity, к проекту подключена supportLib, в файле "styles" всё нормально и в манифесте и для приложения и для активити правильно указаны темы (типа 'Theme.AppCompat'), то, не смотря проект, больше ничем помочь не смогу...

Судя по логам, проблема таки с темами.

Comment: Вот и я о том же.